# how to delete xilinx from my linux mint permanently

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint, xilinx, nosuchfileexception

[image]

I had to manually delete all Xilinx files on my Linux Mint and now every time I open terminal this shows up.I don't know what is the cause. Does anyone now how to get rid of it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your bash environment still tries to source Xilinx ISE.

Please open your .bashrc located at `/home/$USER/.bashrc` and find a line which looks something like

```bash
. /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh
```

or

```bash
source /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/settings64.sh
```

Bash might also source a file which sources a file. You might want to post the contents of `/home/$USER/.bashrc` in your question so we can give you better advice.

Other places to look might include `/home/$USER/.bash_profile` and `/home/$USER/.bash_aliases`, though I think it's rather unlikely you will find it there.

Comment: I just deleted the part with xilinx from bashrc and it's gone thanks for help